# Intellij IDEA 2016.2 high CPU usage

Tags: intellij-idea

I have only one project (an ordinary SpringFramework project) opened. And the IDE is crazy using CPU:

[image]

JVisualVM CPU sample:

[image]

**Note** this happened just recently

Any idea?

Comment: File->Invalidate Caches and restart?

Comment: Yes did that and looks okay now

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The correct answer was posted by @matt-helliwell if you're coming from a version older than `2016.2`.

```
File -> Invalidate Caches and Restart
```

If the above doesn't fix your problem, track this issue: 
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-157837

Comment: Really hope more people finds this solution. I've been having issues with webstorm for 2 weeks where it was taking all CPU and making my machine run hot. This fixed it all.

Answer (score 24):

I invalidated the caches and it solved the problem for some time. But after a couple days Idea (my version is 2017.1.3) started to work slow with some freezing delays again. Finally I increased maximum available memory to 2 Gb (parameter -Xmx in `idea.exe.vmoptions`/`idea64.exe.vmoptions` file) and now it works perfect

Comment: This helped me, the default 7xx mb is too small. Thanks!

Comment: Do the mentioned files even exist on Mac?

Comment: @connexo, you should find something like idea.sh.vmoptions or whatever like that. I don't have mac to check that

Comment: @connexo - For Mac: /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/bin/idea.vmoptions

Comment: Pretty sad that IDEs still assume we are in the days of max 4G RAM. Had to suffer a few times, restart a few times, then landed here for a solution. Pathetic.

Comment: Spoke too soon, this seemed like it was helping but Thar she blew again. None of the solutions here helped me. I do have another git issue  but only with IJ where it reports a corrupt index; so maybe a clean repo may help.

Comment: There seems to be a GUI in "PyCharm | Help | Change Memory Settings" to change the max memory.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/increasing-memory-heap.html

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem by running idea64 bits : 
JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.4\bin\idea64.exe

Another possible solution, my IDEA was very slow because of a huge sql file open which was consuming all my CPU.

Comment: Pretty irrelevant for a Mac user

Comment: True. But it wasn't in the requirements, although screenshots show macOS windows.

Answer (score 1):

It took me a long time to notice this was happening only when opening a specific utility class with more than 1000 lines of code.

This class had maybe 50 public static methods (the reason why it is a utility class...), all pure.

## Edit:

In the bellow (Old version) paragraph I said that this issue was not a looping process... well I was wrong, it WAS a looping process, so this is effectively a BUG.

The bellow class called GlobalLayouts.class has a single static method:

```
public static AdapterEntry<GraphView> getEntry(
                Supplier<Context> contextSupplier,
                ConsumerRegister<Float> highlighter,
                ConsumerRegister<ILineDataSet[]> updatableSet,
                ConsumerRegister<LimitLine[]> updatableLimitLinesSet
        ) {...
```

This method creates a function that captures a portion of the View's scope, it then get's implemented as many times as necessary in a LinearLayout in order to create View instances that require the given logic.

This single static method, which creates an immutable Entry, makes the IDE to infinitely check for "syntax analysis".
If you are in a laptop this will drain the battery very fast... so my recommendation is to click the word: "Highlight: All Problems"

[image]

Because of the bug the window will constantly collapse and expand, making it difficult to click the option, so you'll need to keep the mouse pointed exactly to where the word will be in the future and click it, in my case I aim here:

[image]

If you aim lower the window disappears, then wait until the clickable word gets under your pointer and click, then you'll choose the option "NONE", and the use stops.

The catch is that you'll basically be coding in a NotePad...

## Old version

At first, I thought it was stuck on a loop of "Performing code analysis" because that was the thing running heavily on the background as shown when hovering the mouse above a green check on top of the window of the offending class:

[image]

, but in reality, it was slowly scanning each instance in which the code was being executed in the entire source code.

It took like 45 minutes to scan the entirety of the class, the entire time the CPU usage at max (100%).

Once the class is closed the usage stops.

The issue (at least with AS Dolphin 2022-23) is that the analysis is never memorized, so if the window is closed, and opened later, the analysis begins from 0. So, it never gets cached...